# How android install external library? For example Facebook SDK library

Tags: android, facebook, installation, shared-libraries

I am developing an android application which uses [Facebook SDK library](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) . There are 2 projects run on the emulator: `my application .apk` and `facebook library .apk`.

When I build my project I have only `my application .apk` without facebook library.

So I don't actually understand how this external shared library (facebook sdk) is installed on the real device. Unfortunately I also didn't find this issue in the official documentation.

Another thing which I want to ask is When I develop my own library for several projects how should i provide it to users? Should I post it to the market?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Answer (score 0):

When you build your project, you are linking Facebook SDK as per the instructions listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

when you do that, the apk created has the references for the Facebook SDK and it doesn't require any other apk to be loaded. You only need to install your app apk and to test SSO, install Facebook.apk provided as part of the Android SDK.

Comment: I did that on my HTC and application was crashed because there was not Facebook.apk. And I don't understand this link process, if user don't have facebook.apk how he install it?

Comment: it should not crash, if the facebook.apk is not installed on the handset, SSO should fallback to webview based dialog for authenticating user. Please look at the logs to see why it's crashing.